# Uncaught TypeError: props.addPost is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, typeerror, single-page-application

React writes Uncaught TypeError: props.addPost is not a function.
Wanted to make a post in my app.
Please help.

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./MyPosts.module.css";
import { Post } from "./Post/Post.jsx";
export const MyPosts = (props) => {
  
  let postsElement = props.posts.map((p) => (
    <Post message={p.message} likesCount={p.likesCount} />
  ));

  let newPostElement = React.createRef();

  let addPost = () => {
    let text = newPostElement.current.value;
  =>  props.addPost(text);
    newPostElement.current.value ='';
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.postsBlockN}>
      <h3>My Post</h3>
      <div>
        <div>
          <textarea ref={newPostElement}></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={addPost}>Add Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.postsSN}></div>
      {postsElement}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Do you pass `addPost` function as a prop to the shown component???

Comment: state.js:" export let addPost = (postMessage) => {
  let newPost = {
    id: 7,
    message: postMessage,
    likesCount: 0
  };
  state.profilePage.posts.push(newPost);
  rerenderEntireTree(state);
}"

Answer (score 0):

make sure parent component passing function `addPost`

```js
<MyPosts addPost={()=>{}} />
```

Comment: profile.js "import React from "react";
import { MyPosts } from "./MyPosts/MyPosts.jsx";
import classes from "./Profile.module.css";
import { ProfileInfo } from "./ProfileInfo/ProfileInfo.jsx";

export const Profile = (props) => {
return (
    <div>
      <ProfileInfo />
      <MyPosts posts={props.posts} addPost={props.addPost}/>
    </div>
  );
};"

Comment: please see which parent component first passed `addPost`

Comment: In app.js debugger writes in props is postMessage.

Comment: console log `addPost` to see the type of `addPost`